# How to fix "Undefined property: Mahasiswa::$form_validation"?

Tags: php, codeigniter

> Undefined property: Mahasiswa::$form_validation

I already load the Form helper and Form Validation library.
I'm using `CodeIgniter 3.1.10`.

```
class Mahasiswa extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Mahasiswa_model');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['judul'] = 'Data Mahasiswa';
    $data['mahasiswa'] = $this->Mahasiswa_model->getAllMahasiswa();
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('mahasiswa/index');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function tambah()
{
    $data['judul'] = "Form Tambah Data Mahasiswa";

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'Nama', 'required');

            if ( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )
            {
                    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                    $this->load->view('mahasiswa/tambah');
                    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('mahasiswa');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }

}
```

}

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Mahasiswa::$form_validation
>
> Filename: controllers/Mahasiswa.php
>
> Line Number: 26

Comment: once try it by autoload

Comment: Try to load it on `config/autoload.php`
`$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');`

Comment: i try like that on config/autoload.php `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation');` but still error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the form_validation library in autoload.php in the config folder. because I also had the same issue and it worked for me

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');
```

Answer (score 0):

**First you should load libraries in autoload.php in the config folder. Like this**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation);

$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

Comment: still not working

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation');

since I added 'form_validation' the error became like this

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Mahasiswa_model::$load

Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php

Line Number: 147

Comment: Add    $this->load->helper('form', 'url');  dependencies in controller and also add in autoload.php in config folder. like this $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');